# remove text after a regex until the end of line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, regular-expression

I have a file like this

```
this is a year (2004); this text is not insteresting
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005); blah blah
this another year (2007); irrelevant text
```

I want to cut the line just after the year);

```
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

this is not working

```
sed -E 's/\(.*\)[0-9]{4});\(.*\)/\2/' file
```

How could I do it with sed or awk?

Comment: Would it be correct to say that you want to cut after the last `;` on each line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A valid way to writing what you want is

```
sed -E 's/(.*[0-9]{4}\);).*/\1/' file
```

This will delete all the line characters after the last occurrence of `yyyy);` of each line.

Your attempt was

```
sed -E 's/\(.*\)[0-9]{4});\(.*\)/\2/' file
```

But because of the `-E` flag that enables extended regex, `\( \)` do not delimit matching groups, instead they match literal parenthesis from the file, while `( )` delimit matching groups. So the parenthesis in `[0-9]{4})` is unmatched and sed complains:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 28: Unmatched ) or \)
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is always only one `);`, it's quite simple:

```
$ sed 's/);.*/);/' file 
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

if there can be more and you want to remove everything after the last one:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*)\);.*/\1);/' file 
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

Yours isn't working because you are trying to match a `)` followed by 4 numbers (`\)[0-9]{4}`) but you don't have that in your input. I think you were trying to write something like this:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*[0-9]{4}\);).*/\1/' file
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

Comment: it could be more than one ');' in the line but just one is preceded by a year

Comment: @EmilioGalarraga then please edit your question and add some examples. We can only work with what you show us.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` (assuming the version you have supports `-o` option)

```
$ grep -oE '.*[0-9]{4});' file
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

`-o` option will cause `grep` to print only the matching portions. So, this is not entirely same as `sed` command as the lines not containing this pattern will not be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Method1

```
sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\{4\});\)\(.*\)/\1/' filename
```

output

```
  this is a year (2004);
    singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
    this another year (2007);
```

Method2

```
awk -F ");" '{print $1");"}' filename
```

output

```
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=re.compile(r'.*[0-9]\);')
p=open('o.txt','r')
for i in p:
    z=re.search(k,i)
    print z.group()
```

output

```
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, you cut each line after the last `;`.  This is a simple operation with `sed` that does not require any backreferencing:

```
$ sed 's/;[^;]*$/;/' file
this is a year (2004);
singer elton john; month and year (December, 2005);
this another year (2007);
```

Or, with `awk`:

```
awk -F ';' 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } { $NF=""; print }' file
```